# Make interval of time laravel

Tags: php, laravel, time, php-carbon

i have 2 time: 
start time is `10.00` and end time is `12.00` .

So i want to make like this :
`10.15` `10.30` `10.45` until `12.00`.

The interval of this time is `12`.
So how can i to make the interval of the time?

```
for($i=$time['from'];$i<$time['end'];$i=Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $i)->addMinutes(15))
{
    $time_interval[$i]=Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $i)->toTimeString();        
}
```

How to know if the time have passed the end time?
can i use like this `$i<<times['end']`

Comment: how you are displaying time interval ? which format you want ?

Comment: You can use [`addMinutes`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) function

Comment: i want to display 10:15 10:30 10:45 until 12:00

Answer (score 0):

You could use php's range and array map functions:

```
$start = Carbon::createFromTime(10,0,0);
$range = array_map(function($i) {
    return $start->addMinutes($i * 15);
}, range(1,8,1));
```